# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::connect()

Tags: php, laravel, redis

Running Laravel 5.7 via Homestead.

This is happening in:

```
/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connectors/PhpRedisConnector.php
"line":66
"function":"establishConnection"
```

We are using PHP Redis and in config/database.php:

```
'redis' => [

        'client' => 'phpredis',

        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 6,
        ],

    ],
```

I've seen other answers on here and none of the steps work. There is no redis cluster in use.  PhpRedis extension is installed on VM and confirmed with `php -m`. Redis server is running at 127.0.0.1 and can be connected to outside of the code.

I'm unable to change the code as it works for others. It must be a configuration issue on my VM but I can't see what it could be. If anyone has had a similar issue I'd much appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you are having is because of class naming conflict: `PhpRedisConnector` creates new `\Redis` client, but it seems that you have alias for `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis` facade set up somewhere in your app. `PhpRedisConnector` creates `new Redis` and gets facade object instead.

Try removing this line in your `config/app.php`:

```
'aliases' => [
    ...
    'Redis' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class, // remove this line
    ...
]
```

Comment: I appreicate the answer and do agree that it appears to be a class naming conflict, however this answer does not work.  Just removing the Redis Facade results in an error in the same file `PhpRedisConnector.php` just earlier on in the `createClient` method:  `Class 'Redis' not found`

Comment: @peacemaker then `redis` extension is missing from your PHP or is not enabled. That is the only explanation if `Redis` class is not found. See questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25230399/fatal-error-class-redis-not-found) to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for that, you were right! It appears that although I'd installed php-redis and it was showing in `php -m` output, re-installing it fixed the issue.  I will mark your answer as solved.